# python django django.db.utils.OperationalError: table pybo_question has no column named content error?

Tags: python, django

I was studying django with my book but I have met a unknow error

This is the error
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: table pybo_question has no column named content`

I have two tables in my models.py Question and Answer.

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField()

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

After I finished writing `q.save()` the error came out.

In my python interpreter:

```
from pybo.models import Question, Answer
q = Question(subject=hi', content='hello.' , create_date=timezone.now())
q.save()
```

Comment: Looks like you did not create or apply all migrations.

Comment: 1) python manage.py makemigrations pybo

2) python manage.py migrate
Now try again

Answer (score 0):

1. This type of error occur when you mistakenly do something which affect your database so you have to delete database and migration files in order to create new database and it may be happen when you do something weird with your models use it as a reference https://youtu.be/CJX9Aw-mKGE and Best of Luck
2. I have an advice to use Django admin page to pass values in model field rather than python interpreter
   In your admin.py write

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Question, Answer

admin.site.register(Question)
admin.site.register(Answer)

And visit Admin page you will see your models and can easily add values to field if there is typo error it will notify in web browser thatl like cannot write character,etc

Comment: Thanks for your advice , I'll check.